# Using cin to append to a string C++

Tags: c++, cin

is there a way to use std::cin to append to a string instead of replacing what's inside?

Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Why can't you just `cin` to a different string, and then use `std::string::operator+` to append those strings together?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm sure you can, but from the OP's perspective, there may be a more proper approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> it(std::cin);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> end_it;
    std::string str;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        if (it != end_it) {
            str += *it;
            if (i != 2)
                ++it;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    std::cout << "Res: " << str << "\n";
}
```

but much simpler to use just two `std::string` variables,
one for current input, another for accumulation.